# Converting CSV (polygon coordinates) to polygon feature class (shapefile)?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, convert, csv

I have a CSV table as following :

```
ID;POLYGON
1;(-7.59443,33.55933):(-7.59416,33.55937):(-7.59414,33.55922)
2;(-7.58361,33.56655):(-7.58148,33.56655):(-7.58148,33.56486):(-7.58361,33.56486)
```

The coordinate system used is WGS84. Polygons have no holes and they are all single parts.

I need to convert it to a Polygon feature class/shapefile. I have access to QGIS or ArcGIS, but welcome answers in other software as well.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Do you have any python ability? This wouldn't be too difficult in either QGIS or ArcGIS in python.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about the source of data :/

Comment: @Luke, they have no holes, they are singleparts.
 Thanks for Your interaction

Comment: @AndreSilva, the software to use doesn't matter, i juste need to convert the CSV to polygon/shapfile

Comment: Separated by semicolons

Comment: Please choose exactly one software package. Offering two packages makes this two questions, with two completely different answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a format I'm not familiar with, possibly a custom format.  Below is an ArcGIS arcpy solution that reads in your CSV (assuming only 2 columns, ID and POLYGON!).

```
import csv
import arcpy

csvfile = 'C:/Temp/test.csv'
outpath, outshp = 'C:/Temp', 'test.shp'

outshp = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (
    outpath, outshp, geometry_type='POLYGON',
    spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))

arcpy.AddField_management(outshp, "ID", "LONG")

with open(csvfile) as csvfile, arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outshp, ['ID', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    #Skip header row
    next(csvreader, None)

    for id, coords in csvreader:
        coords = [eval(xy) for xy in coords.split(':')]
        # could also use the following if you don't trust `eval`
        # coords = [map(float, xy[1:-1].split(',')) for xy in coords.split(':')]
        print(id, coords)
        cursor.insertRow([id, coords])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your coordinates to Well-Known Text (WKT) if you open your CSV in Excel and use this formula:

```
="POLYGON(("&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,","," "),"(",""),")",""),":",",")&"))"
```

Where B2 is your existing coordinates.

Then copy/paste values back in so your new CSV has the formula's output, and using QGIS (there is probably a way using ArcGIS too), import it in using the "Create a Layer from a Delimited Text File" option:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you can right-click the layer in the Layers Panel, select "Save As", and save it as a shapefile (you can also change the coordinate system if you want).[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with FME Desktop if you have a license or you can use a fully functional trial license to test it out. Below is a screenshot of the workspace. You need to save the data in csv/text file as per the attached file. The workspace was using FME Desktop 2018.0

[image: FME Workspace Converting the data to Polygon]

The files can be downloaded from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/znzxnx2qyg5q1rq/csv22none.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

```py
import shapefile
import csv
import ast
with open(r"Sample_Data.csv", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    # dict create
    dictReader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    # create writable shapefile
    w = shapefile.Writer('Sample_Data.shp')
    # create attribute
    w.field('id', 'C')
    w.field('nieghborho', 'C')
    w.field('plan_no', 'C')
    # row from dict
    for row in dictReader:
        # write row attribute
        w.record(row['id'], row['nieghborhood'], row['plan_no'])
        # write geom
        w.poly([ast.literal_eval(row['geom'])])
    # create prj file
    prj = open("Sample_Data.prj", "w")
    epsg = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",'
    epsg += 'DATUM["WGS_1984",'
    epsg += 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]]'
    epsg += ',PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],'
    epsg += 'UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
    # save prj file
    prj.write(epsg)
    # close above shapefile
    w.close()
```